# jQuery best practice checkbox show/hide table rows and keep state on page refresh

Tags: jquery

What is the best practice for writing something like this in jQuery? The script below works fine, but something tells me there’s a better.  I have a checkbox base that triggers a toggle function that hides a couple rows in a table when checked and vice-versa when unchecked.

```
$("#checkboxID").change(function(){     
   $("#tableID tr.rowClass").toggle(); 
});
```

Whenever checkbox is checked and the page is refreshes the row are display which should stay hidden. I solved this issue by add this script.

```
if($("#checkboxID").attr("checked")){
    $("#tableID tr.rowClass").hide();
}else{
    $("#tableID tr.rowClass").show();
}
$("#checkboxID").change(function(){     
   $("#tableID tr.rowClass").toggle(); 
});
```

Is this acceptable or is there a better(proper) way of going this. Thanks i advance for your insight.

Comment: do you actually have a problem that you are trying to solve, or are you asking if your code is..... ok.... that's very opinionated if that's really what you're asking.

Comment: You could do this with css alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
$("#checkboxID").change(function(){
    var self = this;
    $("#tableID tr.rowClass").toggle(!self.checked); 
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XLAHC/).

With the given HTML:

```
<label for="checkboxID">tick/untick</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxID" />
<table id="tableID">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="rowClass">
            <td>First child cell of '.rowClass'</td>
            <td>Second child cell of '.rowClass'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>No class for this row</td>
            <td>(Still no class)</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With CSS, in compliant browsers, you could also use:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #tableID tr.rowClass {
    display: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XLAHC/1/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: Hi David, I just tested JS Fiddle and it works and look cleaner. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This would be a best practice:

```
$("#checkboxID").change(function(){
    $("#tableID tr.rowClass").toggle(!this.checked); 
});
```

Here is a working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zsal/vkvSZ/1/

Comment: Thanks for your respond but when I load the frame in the link provided and the checkbox remains checked but rows are also there. The rows should remain hidden on a page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with .is(":checked"):

```
if($("#checkboxID").is(":checked")){

   $("#tableID tr.rowClass").hide();

}else{

    $("#tableID tr.rowClass").show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this does like a bit cleaner than what I've got.